# Lightning Data Service - Get record value during Component Initialization in Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service

I have a quick action in Account object which loads a Lightning Component. I need to get the record values during initialization (in the doInit function) in the JS Controller without using Apex. I tried this using LDS, but with no luck.

What's the best approach for this scenario.

I am attaching my Component and Controller:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" 
            access="global">

        <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
        <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
        <aura:attribute name="recordInfo" type="Object" />
        <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
        <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
        <aura:attribute name="curView" type="String" /> 
        <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoaderId"
                        layoutType="FULL"
                        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                        targetRecord="{!v.recordInfo}"                           
                        targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                        targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                        mode="VIEW"
                        />
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular slds-text-align_center">
            <lightning:formattedText title="text" value="{!v.simpleRecord.Name}" /> <!--DISPLAYING THE VALUE HERE-->
        </div>


<!--<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/> -->
```

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('insidde init:::');
    console.log("account id:::::" + component.get("v.recordId"));
    console.log("account id:::::" + component.get("v.simpleRecord")); //GETTING NULL VALUE HERE
    console.log("account id:::::" + component.get("v.recordInfo"));

}})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While working with "force:recordData" and if you want to get the values in the lightning controller you have to use the standard attribute of the "force:recordData" i.e; "recordUpdated".
Please have a look at this sample code.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  /> // in Component.
```

In controller

```
handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
        // get the fields that changed for this record
        var changedFields = eventParams.changedFields;
        console.log('Fields that are changed: ' + JSON.stringify(changedFields));
        // record is changed, so refresh the component (or other component logic)
        var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Saved",
            "message": "The record was updated."
        });
        resultsToast.fire();

    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
        console.log("account loaded:::::" + component.get("v.simpleRecord"));
        // record is loaded in the cache
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
        // record is deleted and removed from the cache
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
        // there’s an error while loading, saving or deleting the record
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Thanks
Ram Agarawal

Answer (score 4):

Any call to the server is inherently asynchronous: the browser issues a request to the network, the request traverses the network, the server processes the request and issues a response, the response traverses the network, and the client processes the response.

In contrast the component `init` event is fired synchronously when the component is created. This means you must plan for all server responses to not be available when `init` is fired.

Apex and Lightning Data Service (`force:recordData`) may trigger a server request; therefore, they are inherently asynchronous in how they provision data.

A declarative approach to handle this asynchronous behavior with `force:recordData` is to use `<aura:if>` to display separate UI for loading, error, and success states.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="targetFields" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="targetError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="curView" type="String" /> 
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoaderId"
                    layoutType="FULL"
                    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    targetError="{!v.targetError}"
                    targetFields="{!v.targetFields}"
                    mode="VIEW"
                    />
    <!-- LOADING -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!and(empty(v.targetFields),empty(v.targetErrors))}">
        <!-- loading message --> 
    </aura:if>

    <!-- SUCCESS -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.targetFields))}">
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular slds-text-align_center">
            <lightning:formattedText title="text" value="{!v.targetFields.Name}" />
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <!-- ERROR -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.targetError))}">
        <!-- show error -->
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

If you require running logic when the record data is loaded, use the `recordUpdated` event. You still can use the `<aura:if>` approach above but augment the `force:recordData` tag and implement the handler, like:

```
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoaderId"
                    layoutType="FULL"
                    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    targetError="{!v.targetError}"
                    targetFields="{!v.targetFields}"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"
                    mode="VIEW"
                    />
```

And in your controller:

```
({
    recordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {

    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
    if (changeType === "ERROR") { /* handle error; do this first! */ }
    else if (changeType === "LOADED") { /* handle record load */ }
    else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
    else if (changeType === "CHANGED") { /* handle record change */ }
})
```